# How to find project dependencies in eclipse? how eclipse builds the class path?

Tags: eclipse

There is a project that in some way other project indirectly depends on. I'm trying to find the path of dependencies or the dependencies graph in eclipse but can't find a way.

any way to do that ?

Answer (score 5):

Right-click the project, then select "Properties", then "Java Build Path". The tabs "Projects" and "Libraries" list what the project depends on. Note that the "Order and Export" tab alllows you to have indirect dependencies.

All the information here is saved in a file named `.classpath` in the project; if you want to find specific dependencies in a large workspace, then doing a text search over these files would be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Eclipse Project Dependencies Viewer (https://code.google.com/p/epdv/). It'll give you a nice diagram of your project dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately, the download is not available any more. The project was moved to code archive and is apparently dead...

Comment: It seems that a copy of the project was exported to GitHub - https://github.com/Dabada/epdv

Answer (score 0):

There is command based option as well.
Go to the root folder of your project(you will see pom file in there)
On your command prompt type "mvn dependency:tree", this should print all the dependency your project has on your console.

You can redirect console output to a file, in case dependency tree is too big to fit in console; it is always easy to review this in a file.