# Eclipse know where a project is linked

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Should be a simple question for some, but couldn't find an answer, hence this question.

Before deleting a project, how to know where that particular project is used. Deleting without checking where it is being referred to causes all dependent projects to fail.

I had to manually check all projects before deleting a project. There must be a simple way to check the dependencies of a project.

Comment: If you are using gradle,It will be available in the setting.gradle in parent project. check the below link for clarification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310314/how-to-find-project-dependencies-in-eclipse-how-eclipse-builds-the-class-path

Answer (score 1):

With an openend project you can perform a Delet action and see the "preview". There are listed your delete and the delete-related ations (like server cleanup).

More ist not possible as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

You can go in your eclipse projects folder and do `grep -r -i -l 'project_name or dependency' ./` to see all files with this references.

You can prepend `find . | grep "\pom.xml$" | xargs cat -n |` to this to limit the search to pom.xml if you are using Maven.

You can do this in Eclipse by doing a "file search" by pressing F8 or going in Search > File menu. It will list all projects having those occurences in your *opened* projects in Eclipse.