# Can't get Selenium,Ecplise to give me access to the methods to use for automation

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, junit

This is my first time posting so please be patient.

I know some basic java and am trying to do a course on Selenium but it does not give me access to the necessary methods to perform these tasks in the code itself.

- I have tried 3 different courses and followed exactly how they set up the environment with the same issues.
- I have tried reinstalling Maven, Selenium, and Java.
- I have tried fiddling with the settings.xml but I'm not even sure that could be the problem and it didn't seem to have any effect.
- I have been trying for more than a week to fix this but nothing helps.

It's not showing it in the code but the problem areas in order are:

- org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
- ChromeDriver
- driver = new ChromeDriver
- For all of them it says cannot be resolved to a type

```
package firstSeleniumScipt;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WorkingWithChrome {
       
    ChromeDriver driver;
    String url = "https://test.qatechhub.com/";
    
    public void invokeBrowser () {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maxamize();
        driver.get(url);
    }
    
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close(); // To close current active window
      //driver.quit();  // To close all the windows
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WorkingWithChrome wc = new WorkingWithChrome();
        wc.invokeBrowser();
        wc.closeBrowser();
    }

}
```

This is the error I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    at firstSeleniumScipt.WorkingWithChrome.main(WorkingWithChrome.java:22)
```

Here is my Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>QATechHubProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>QATechHubProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm not sure if anything is missing but there are at least no errors

[This is my Java Build Path, Projects and Libraries. Is this correct?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo5Aj.png)

---

I have added webdrivermanager:5.2.0 &
selenium-chrome-driver:4.2.2 with no change to the code errors.

Although when I execute "echo %PATH%" It does not show me the directory for Selenium. When I set the path using "setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\WebDriver\bin" but with my own location it says "Specified value was saved" But it still does not show.

Comment: How did you setup your project? How does your pom look like?

Comment: seems like you'd need a constructor for WorkingWithChrome... something like   public WorkingWithChrome(String[] args) {.... }   (You don't need args, but not bad to pass those in case you want to use them in the future.)

Comment: Did you follow the installation steps: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/ ?

Comment: it might not be finding a type here... make sure you've got the necessary dependencies included in your project... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310314/how-to-find-project-dependencies-in-eclipse-how-eclipse-builds-the-class-path

Comment: also if you are using Selenium 4 and adding dependencies manually, be sure to leave out all the "-sources" jars.  Those may conflict when resolving imports/types.